# overwriting map with map possible with <algorithm>?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, copy, transform

I would like to do the following but it seems it is not possible. I am no expert on STL.

```
typedef std::map<int,int> CMap;

CMap m1;
m1[0] = 10;
m1[1] = 11;
m1[2] = 12;

CMap m2;
m2[20] = 30;
m2[21] = 31;
m2[22] = 32;

std::copy( m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin() );
```

Is there a way to do this using an algorithm (C++98)? Could it be done with transform() or replace()? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103532/copy-stdmap-data-to-another-map

Comment: Maybe you could use [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) for the last argument?

Comment: @Morb: Thanks. insert() is of course possible. I wondered if it is also possible doing likewise with an algorithm.

Comment: @Joachim: Thanks. That is one way that I did not consider. Actually I did not specify what I want to do properly. I would like to have m2 overwritten by m1. Would that also be possible?

Comment: Better clarify that in the question itself.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
m2 = m1;
```

Or even this if you like:

```
m2.swap(m1);
```

And there is this too:

```
std::copy(m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter(m2, m2.end()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first two overwrite which is good but the third will just append as I understand. Is there a way to overwrite using copy()?

Comment: @Lorenz You could overwrite using `std::copy()` if you created your own `iterator` as `std::insert_iterator` will only insert if there is not a value already present. TBH you might as well just write a loop as any method is going to at least require you to write a functor. If you have `C++11` a simple range based for loop would do it: `for(auto&& p: m1) m2[p.first] = p.second;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did not think of the possibility to write a specific iterator. Now clear.